# Microsoft Word remove paragraph that contains specific word in the middle of the paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, wildcards

This is my first post here so please be gentle. Ok, now that this is done let's get to work: In my free time I read some web novels and stuff like that, which I get using web-scrappers and stuff. Then I save that scrapped stuff in some docx file and there are usually 100 chapters in 1 file. And this is where the interesting stuff happens.

Chapter formating is like this: Title chapter is in new page, there is 1 paragraph space and then there is chapter text. 80% of the time in first few paragraphs (sometimes there is 1 row, sometimes 2, and sometimes there are none) are translators words, where he usually asks for money or mentions Patreon. For example

> **Chapter 1: Title**
>
> oasdasd asdasdasd Patreon sdasd asdasd asda
>
> Text texttexttext texttexttext text
>   PAGE BREAK
>
> **Chapter 2: Title the Return**
>
> texttexttext texttext text
>   PAGE BREAK
>
> **Chapter 3: Titleception**
>
> oasdasd Patreon again sdasd asdasd asda
>
> Text texttexttext texttexttext text

So I thought I'll use wildcards to remove the paragraph that contains the word "Patreon". It would be easy to do so if the paragraph starts with that word but it's not, it's in the middle of paragraph.

I've tried the `(Chapter ???*^13)(* Patreon *^13)(*)` to replace with `\1\3` but it's not working as intended, especially if the paragraph doesn't contain the word Patreon, then it selects everything between the 2 occurrences, like between chapter 1 and chapter 3 in this example.

Please, someone help me with this simple wildcard

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using a macro, then it's quite simple with the following few lines of code.

To insert a macro, press Alt+F11 on your keyboard. 
Then from the menu bar on top, select insert > module.

Inside the module, paste the following code:

```
Sub delete_para()

num_para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count 'checks the number of paragraphs in the document

For i = 1 To num_para
    'select the paragraphs one by one
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(num_para + 1 - i).Range.Select 

    'check if the required word exists in the pparagraph
    x = Selection.Find.Execute("atreon") 

    'if it does, then select the paragraph and delete it
    If x = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(num_para + 1 - i).Range.Select
        Selection.delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Once you are done defining the macro, go back to your document. In the Developer tab of the ribbon, Click on Macros. Your macro will show up there. Select it and click the run button.

The lines starting with ' character are comments, just for understanding the code. I have searched only for *atreon* because the P can be either capital or small and I couldn't make this code work in a non-case-sensitive way.

I have also selected the paragraphs from the last because otherwise when it deletes the 3rd para, the 4th para becomes the third para. But in the next step it selects the 4th para, thereby skipping the previous paragraph. Selecting paragraphs from the last solves this problem. Some paragraphs are checked twice, but that doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple wildcard replace, on condition that you never
use the word `Patreon` followed by a blank in your text.
Anything more complicated would require a VBA macro.

Find what: `(*)Patreon (*)`
Replace with: `\1\2`

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think this will remove the whole paragraph containing the word, which is was the OP asked for. - "I'll use wildcards to remove the paragraph that contains the word "Patreon"

Comment: @DavidPostill: I might have misunderstood the poster. From his attempted wildcard strings I understood that he would like to get rid of this one word. I will wait for his answer before doing this otherwise.